# Setting AlertDialog width to fit the size of the fixed size imageview using builder.setView()

Tags: java, android, android-layout, kotlin

I'm new to android development, I want to set AlertDialog to display an imageview with a fixed size width = 150dp , height = 150dp. However, when the image is smaller than the parent width it has a background space that I want to dispose of.

I've tried to `dialog.setView(dialogview,0,0,0,0).create()` doesn't work, multiple layout change of width and height both parent layout and imageview layout, doesn't work .
set `dialog.window?.setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT))`, doesn't work and other various stuff.

This is my XML file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="horizontal"
          android:background="#44403c"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:gravity="center"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center">
<pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifImageView 
android:layout_width="150dp" android:layout_height="160dp"                                 
android:src="@drawable/tickgifcrop"                                     
android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
```

This is my kotlin code :

```
val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
val progressdialogview = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.successdialog,null)
builder.setCancelable(false)
builder.setView(progressdialogview)
val dialog = builder.create()
dialog.show()
dialog.window?.setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT))
```

[This is what it look like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mVMda.png)

Answer (score 0):

Change the size of parent layout to `wrap_content`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:background="@android:color/transparent"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:gravity="center"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center">
    <pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifImageView 
    android:layout_width="150dp" android:layout_height="160dp"                                 
    android:src="@drawable/tickgifcrop"                                     
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
```

And add the following thing to your code after `dialog.show()`

```
val lp = WindowManager.LayoutParams()
        lp.copyFrom(dialog.window?.attributes)
        lp.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        lp.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT

       dialog.window?.attributes = lp
```

to remove the shadow behind the dialog add

```
dialog.window?.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND)
```

Comment: one thing, make your parent view transparent android:background="@android:color/transparent"